# df command shows 100% full, even after deleting files it shows same usage (100%)

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, flash-memory

Nand Flash storage partition shows as 100% full with df command. When manually calculated the usage it is about 7-80%(max) only. Deleted few files (say around 50~60MB), still df command output did not change. I can not create a new file, error: "there is no space left on the storage device". Tried `sync` command, no difference.

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   262144     20780    241364   8% /tmp
tmpfs                      512         0       512   0% /dev
/dev/ubi0_0            1275540   1275540         0  100% /storage
```

When the actual storage space is not full (as per the manual calculation), why doe df command shows it as 100% full?

Comment: check the output of `losetup -a`, if it shows any unmounted loop devices.

Comment: What were the files that you deleted, could there be another process holding them open so they have not been fully removed? Check `lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'` for any files that have been deleted but are still being held open.

Comment: No, I checked that there is no file is being held open after deletion. Basically I have deleted few log file.

Comment: How did you delete the files with rm or filemanager?

Comment: @sai sasanka... Unfortunately 'losetup' is not available and I can't install it as well.

Comment: @Bahamut files were deleted with rm

Comment: The files you deleted was that the files that were being used by some process.. in that case please try to restart the process this will free up the space

Comment: How did you check the files were not being held open by some process? Does the problem persist after the Windows Universal Solution (TM) (a.k.a. reboot)?

Comment: Un-mounting the partition, mounting again and reboot did worked. But why didn't df output updated before?

Comment: `sync` command should have been tried before umount/mount.

Comment: Is it possible that some thing is filling the volume quickly? Use `du` to find out where how much space is used and how this changes after deleting files. It may also make sense to run `fsck`.

Comment: sync command did not help before reboot. There is nothing which could be noticed that can fill the volume so fast.

Comment: sync doesn't change what you see in df. It syncs the RAM buffer with the disk, but df will always show you the actual size in the FS (buffered or not). The only thing sync does is making sure the files are still deleted when you reset the computer before the buffered operation is written to disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A reboot and re-mount would solve the problem I believe.

**Reason:** The reason behind this is that `df` utilize [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) system call to get the File system stat. What it means that it checks open kernel file descriptors to count free space as it named (df = disk free). You will get a different result if you use `du`. `df` showing 100% used because the files were deleted are not yet released from the kernel file descriptor.

May be the following scenario will help you to understand:

1. A running process named `xyz.service` are using a file named `something.dump` which resides at `/storage` partition.
2. The `file discriptor` of `something.dump` is listed in the `process file descriptor table` of `xyz.service`.
3. Then you deleted `something.dump` but `xyz.service` is still running.
4. The `xyz.service` is not aware of the updated status of `something.dump` file. So file descriptor of `something.dump` is still there.
5. Then you ran `df` command and kernel checked all the process table to see used filed descriptor to calculate free space.
6. Kernel saw that the `inodes` of that `something.dump` file is still listed at the `xyz.service` process's file descriptor table. So it counts `something.dump` is still at the file system hence it doesn't consider something.dump's inodes as free. Which is the reason you are seeing more usage.
7. So when you `SIGKILL` `xyz.service` those inodes will be released and you probably can see the free spaces.
8. Restarting the system will do the same thing as step 7.

Answer (score 0):

Additional reason: you have copies of these files in a snapshot if you use file systems like `btrfs` and use snapshots.